# How to check using the command line which display manager is running?

Tags: command-line, xorg, desktop-environments

How can I determine the name of the display manager in use solely by using the command line?

Comment: i do not want to be excluded from discussion because of my lexical disabilities, i asked for the display manager, the link you gave me is about the window manager.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20370/is-there-a-simple-linux-command-that-will-tell-me-what-my-display-manager-is

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Short answer:

As mentioned in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20376/95917) on Unix & Linux, you should be able to get that from:

```
cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

I tried it on both `Unity` and `XFCE`, both worked.

Comment: very good, i have mdm

Comment: `loginctl` (systemd) show the display manager on each seat. Maybe is a better way, might work on Wayland

Comment: `cat: /etc/X11/default-display-manager: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

Other way to find more detailed information about the window manager you're using is by running either `neofetch` or `screenfetch`. Both are similar and are available in Debian repositories. I install Neofetch and it show my WM also to be WM: Mutter.[image: Result of screenfetch and neofetch]

you can install them in debian systems CLI by :

```
sudo apt install neofetch screenfetch
```